# Getting black controls when running linux on vmware on windows

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware

I want to run ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I want to put the graphics in it, but when I open it, I get this.

I used this command

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```

to put the desktop version on it.

Also I have an intel chipset, and nvidia 420m graphics card.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're running it inside of VMware you need to install VMware Tools into the VM Guest (Ubuntu). Typically this would be done via a pulldown but since you're using what looks to be VMware Player you'll need to copy the ISO file into the VM and then mount it and install it yourself manually.

You can read more about how to do this on the VMware Kowledge Base (KB).

- [Installing VMware Tools in an Ubuntu virtual machine (1022525)](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1022525)

Comment: Actually I tried disabling the 3d hardware acceleration in the vmware settings, and it did work, but the text was looking slightly funny. Like some characters overlap.

Comment: @omega - perhaps you could update your Q and include the details of what you did?